# Поиск слова в строке и стоп слова re.search

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть >100 строк:

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2. Lorem ipsum nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi .
3. Enim ad minima veniam, quis adipiscing elit.
```

.....
Есть запрещенные слова:

```
1. ipsum
2. ullamco
```

.....
Есть стоп слово:

```
1. amet
2. quis
```

.....

Если в заголовке найдется запрещенное слово но не найдется стоп слова - вывести результат в консоль

Comment: из вопроса непонятно чем отличаются запрещенные слова от стоп-слов?

Comment: @iksuy поправил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
import re

text = """\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.
Enim ad minima veniam, quis adipiscing elit.
"""

for line in text.splitlines():
    # Если есть запрещенное слово, но нет стоп-слова
    if re.search('ipsum|ullamco', line) and not re.search('amet|quis', line):
        print(line)
```

Консоль:

```
Lorem ipsum nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.
```

---

**UPD.**

```
def match_line(line):
    return ('ullamco' in line and 'quis' not in line) \
           or ('ipsum' in line and 'amet' not in line)

for line in text.splitlines():
    if match_line(line):
        print(line)
```

Comment: А если к примеру у каждого запрещенного слова есть свои стоп слова? Например в ipsum есть стоп слово amet а в ullamco  этого стоп слова не будет

Comment: @OuFinx, добавил пример в UPD. Без регулярок, но мне кажется что так проще будет